# Invalid domain localhost

Tags: reactjs, node.js, compilation

when I host a node application in IIS in order to work with react. Invalid domain localhost error I am getting... could anyone please tell me what is the error and solution for the error. I require react and node local environment
React alone is working fine.

Invalid domain localhost error

Comment: Could you please provide more context here? What is `IIS`? How exactly do you run it? How do you host the app?

Comment: can you share IIS configuration? 1) node will serve files, IIS should proxy nodejs, 2) node will generate react files, so IIS will serve files